# Keeping a foreground service alive with binding

Tags: android, service

I've built a service that uses `startForeground()` to stay alive, but I need to use binding to   connect it to my activities.

It turns out that even if the service is running in the foreground, it's still killed when all activities unbind from it.  How can I keep the service alive, even when no activities are bound to it?

Comment: This is really important to mention here, the docs does not specify this issue anywhere. _A foreground service loses its purity of being foreground once it is bound to a client_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised this works, but you can actually call `startService()` *from the service you're starting*.  This still works if `onStartCommand()` is not implemented; just make sure that you call `stopSelf()` to clean up at some other point.

An example service:

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {

    public static final int START = 1;
    public static final int STOP = 2;

    final Messenger messenger = new Messenger( new IncomingHandler() );

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind( Intent intent ){
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }

    private Notification makeNotification(){
        // build your foreground notification here
    }

    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage( Message msg ){
            switch( msg.what ){
            case START:
               startService( new Intent( this, ForegroundService.class ) );
               startForeground( MY_NOTIFICATION, makeNotification() );
               break;

            case STOP:
                stopForeground( true );
                stopSelf();
                break;    

            default:
                super.handleMessage( msg );    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just to make it clear: does this solve the scenario where you first bind to the service, and then inside the service you decide to make it foreground ?

Comment: This is not an answer for question